# Is it required to have 1 table schema in 1 s3 folder , so that crawler can pick the data in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

When I try to have multiple files in an s3 folder(with different tables schemas)  and use the location to create multiple tables using crawler and AWS glue , the athena doesnt detect any data and it gives blank data . However if we have files with only single table schema (tables with same column structure ) then , it detects the data well . So the question is , Is there a way athena can create multiple tables with different structures from the same s3 folder ?

I have tried creating different folders for different files and crawler picks up the table schema well and it gives us the exact result , However it is not feasible as creating different folders for 100's of files is not a Solution . Hence searching for another way.

Answer (score 0):

When defining a table in Amazon Athena (and AWS Glue), the `location` parameter should point to a folder path in an Amazon S3 bucket.

When running a query, Athena will **look in *every* file in that folder, including sub-folders**.

Therefore, you should **only keep files of the same format (and schema) in that directory** and all of its subdirectories. All of these files will populate the one table.

Do *not* put multiple files in the same directory if they are meant to populate different tables or have different schemas.

Comment: Does that mean if we have 1000 tables of different table structures , they should be loaded into separate folders(1000 folders) ? Or we have some solution to that ?

Comment: Yes. If you have 1000 tables, they they will all need to be in separate directories. Athena will read _all files_ in the given `location`, including subfolders.